# Transformation of images in mobile apps

Tags: android, actionscript-3, image, mobile, air

I tried to create a simple collage designer for Android. Each image can be moved, rotated, scaled. Use this code:

```
var os:Sprite = new Sprite();
os.cacheAsBitmap = true;
                os.cacheAsBitmapMatrix = new Matrix();
                Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
                if (Multitouch.supportsGestureEvents){
                    os.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ROTATE , onRotate );
                    os.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM , onZoom);
                    os.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_PAN , onPan);
                }
                os.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);
                os.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp);

protected function onRotate(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
            {
                event.target.rotation += event.rotation;
            }

            protected function onZoom(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
            {
                event.target.scaleX *= event.scaleX;
                event.target.scaleY *= event.scaleY;
            }

            protected function onPan(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
            {
                event.target.x = event.offsetX;
                event.target.y = event.offsetY;
            }
            protected function onDown(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                os.startDrag();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }

            protected function onUp(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                os.stopDrag();
            }
```

However, scaling images is not smooth, the image suddenly changes size, motion pull. Although I have quite a powerful device for testing. I can not use a standard way using markers, because the images are quite small, and tap your finger into the marker will be difficult.

Prompt code examples how this can be implemented, please.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using "gpu" renderMode to test?
And try use bitmap instead